# Level set corresponding to the value $0$ for $f(x,y,z)=y^3-z^3$ is a smooth surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was attempting exercises in Vector Calculus by Peter Baxandall. [image]

**Definition $3.8.11$:** A set $S \subseteq \Bbb R^m$ is called a smooth surface if $S$ is a level set of a $C^1$ function $f: D \subseteq \Bbb R^m \rightarrow \Bbb R~$ s.t $~\text {grad}~ f(x) \ne 0~\forall~x \in S$

**My Argument:**

> We can see that $S$ is the level set corresponding to the value $0$ of the $C^1$ function $f:D \subseteq \Bbb R^m \rightarrow \Bbb R~|~f(x,y,z)=y^3-z^3.~~~\therefore~\text{grad}f(x,y,z) = \Big(0,3y^2,-3z^2\Big)$. Clearly, $\text{grad}f(0,0,0)=0$ and $(0,0,0) \in S$. Thus, $S$ cannot be a smooth surface.
> **Why does $3.8.11$ not apply to the above function?**

Could someone point out any error in the above argument? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite the definition slightly:

> **Definition $3.8.11$**
>
> A set $S\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is called a smooth surface if **there exists** an open set $D\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ and a function $f:D\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $S = f^{-1}\left(\{0\}\right)$ and for every $x\in S$, $(\text{grad } f)(x) \neq 0$.

Note the "there exists" in the definition. Nowhere in the definition does it say anything about uniqueness. In other words, just because the given function $F$ which doesn't satisfy that condition, it does not mean $S$ is not a smooth surface. Just because $F$ does not satisfy the condition, it doesn't mean no other function can satisfy that condition.

For example, just because I can't run a $100$m dash in $9.58$ seconds, it doesn't mean nobody else can... Usain Bolt certainly can (and did) $\ddot{\smile}$.

For example, consider $\phi:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}$ given by $\phi(x,y,z) = y-z$. What is the level set $\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$? What is its gradient?

Comment: The level set $\phi^{-1}(\{0\})=(x,y,y)$. Grad $f=(1,1,-1)$

Comment: @MathMan therefore, what can you conclude?

Comment: Thus, the level set is smooth according to definition?

Comment: @MathMan yes, and do you see that this level set equals the $S$ given in your question?

Comment: aaahh... So we just found another function which fits the criteria?

Comment: @MathMan yes exactly. And in this case there are actually infinitely many other functions which fit the criteria, like $(x,y,z) \mapsto 2(y-z)$ or $(x,y,z) \mapsto 3(y-z)$. More generally, for any $\alpha\in \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, the level set of the function $(x,y,z) \mapsto \alpha\cdot(y-z)$ equals $S$, and this function satisfies all the requirements of that definition.

Comment: Thank you. got it.